# Save dynamic textarea array to a corresponding number

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdownlist with 1 through 5 as values, and I need to create description textareas for each number that will belong to a series going up by the amount chosen from the dropdownlist. for example if a user selects 3 from the dropdownlist, I need to have a textarea for 5001, 5002, 5003. How do I create the textarea fields dynamically based on the value in the dropdownlist, and save textarea 1 with the series number 5001, etc? This is inside an MVC partial view that uses Html.BeginCollectionItem Inside an Html.BeginForm on my main page. Here is what the html looks like if it helps:

```
<label>Amount: </label> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.vCount)

//this needs to be dynamic for how ever many numbers I'm generating
<div class="label-wrapper"> 
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)
```

Edit:

I've got some of this figured out. I've added more descriptions in the view model, but I'm having problems with parent divs and selects having either the same id, or not sure how to work with individual divs and selects with dynamic ids. Since my partial view can be duplicated over and over, how do I know what inputs to hide or show when the selects are the same? It works fine when there is only one dvGenPart, but when I add another nothing is triggered by the dropdownlist change. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="dvGenPart" title="Generate Drawing #" style="height:300px;">
<br />
<br />
    <label style="width:120px;">Series:</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SeriesNumber_id, Model.vSeries, "-- Select Series --") <label>Amount: </label> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.vCount, new { @id="ddlSelectedValue"})
    <br />
<div class="label-wrapper" id="dvDescription1">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description1)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description1)
    <br />
</div>
<div class="label-wrapper" id="dvDescription2" style="display:none">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description2)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description2)
    <br />
</div>
<div class="label-wrapper" id="dvDescription3" style="display:none">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description3)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description3)
    <br />
</div>
<div class="label-wrapper" id="dvDescription4" style="display:none">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description4)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description4)
    <br />
</div>
<div class="label-wrapper" id="dvDescription5" style="display:none">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description5)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description5)
    <br />
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
$(document).on("change", "#ddlSelectedValue", function () {
    var vSelectedVal = parseInt($("select").val());

    switch (vSelectedVal) {
        case 1:
            $("#dvDescription2").hide();
            $("#dvDescription3").hide();
            $("#dvDescription4").hide();
            $("#dvDescription5").hide();
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#dvDescription2").show();
            $("#dvDescription3").hide();
            $("#dvDescription4").hide();
            $("#dvDescription5").hide();
            break;
        case 3:
            $("#dvDescription2").show();
            $("#dvDescription3").show();
            $("#dvDescription4").hide();
            $("#dvDescription5").hide();
            break;
        case 4:
            $("#dvDescription2").show();
            $("#dvDescription3").show();
            $("#dvDescription4").show();
            $("#dvDescription5").hide();
            break;
        case 5:
            $("#dvDescription2").show();
            $("#dvDescription3").show();
            $("#dvDescription4").show();
            $("#dvDescription5").show();
            break;
    }

});
```

[image: Not Working]

Here is how the same partial view gets loaded:

```
<div id="dvDrawNumPost">
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewDrawingNum", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "genDrawForm", @class = "english-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="dlgGenDraw">
        <div id="dvNewDraw" style="clear:both;">
            @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.NewDrawNums.Count(); i++)
            {

                @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.NewDrawNums[i])
            }
        </div>
        <br />

        @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Drawing #", "CreateNewDrawNum", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "dvNewDraw" }, new { @class = "ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only AddDrawbtn" })

        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmitNewDraw" name="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user picking the number of fields happens client-side, so generating the associated textareas must occur there as well, unless you want an intervening post. In other words, you *could* have the user select a number and submit. Then, you return a new page back from the server with that number of textareas. However, I don't think that's what you want.

So, since this needs to happen client side, that means you need to bind to the dropdown's change event and somehow generate the textareas via JavaScript:

```
$('#SelectedValue').on('change', function () {
    var numberOfTextareas = $(this).val();
    // generate textareas
});
```

How you want to generate the textareas is entirely for you to decide. You could simply use JavaScript to manually create the elements and insert them into the DOM. You could issue an AJAX request to some endpoint where you pass the number and it returns a partial view that renders that many textareas. Or, you could use something like Knockout or Angular to generate it for you based on a template.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will give this a try tonight.

Comment: Hi @Chris Pratt I have edited my initial question. Your answer helped me get where I am, but I'm not sure how to work with the multiple select on change events. What is the best way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. If you mean that the situation is such that whenever someone selects a new series, they must also select a new amount of textareas, that's achieve easily enough by just binding to the change event of the series dropdown and using that to clear the value for the number of textareas dropdown, which will then fire the change for that dropdown as well.

Comment: First, thank you very much for taking the time to try and help me. I really appreciate it. I've added an image to hopefully help explain. Basically I have the problem of both selects having the same id, so only the top one works with my select on change. I can't figure out how to get them both to work. I think I'll need dynamic ids, but how do I work with the descriptions under that dynamic id?

Comment: Well, first off, ids must be unique across the page. Having different elements with the same id is invalid HTML. I'd have to see how you're actually generating this repeating set of fields, but in general, Razor should generate unique ids if you handle things as they should be. So, given that you'll need to tie this functionality to multiple elements all with different ids, then you need to add a class, and bind to the class instead.

Comment: Ok, I've added code to show how I load the same partial view however many times the user wants to. Will the same class on different elements work for change events in that specific partial view?

Comment: Based on the code you've posted, unique ids should be being generated. Regardless, yes, if you select the class and bind to that, it will bind to all instances of that class *which are currently present on the page*. It shouldn't be an issue based on your code, but it's good to know, in general, that if you were to do something like add another set of the fields via an AJAX request or something, that field would not be bound. If you end up needing to do something like that, you'll need to bind to a parent element and delegate to the class.